# c# search datagridview with numbers

Tags: c#, datagridview

I need to search for the product ID which is number in datagridview.

Error is:

> Cannot perform Like operation system.int32 and system.string

Code is:

```
 dv.RowFilter = string.Format("ProductID like '%{0}%' ", textOrderSearch.Text);
```

Comment: `DataView.RowFilter` not `DataGridView.RowFilter`

Comment: I did not use DataGridView sir, i used DataView, That is what dv stands for thank you.

Comment: look at your title, your question body and the tag

Comment: I'm sorry and thank you for pointing that out sir.

Comment: Thank you sir and sorry for the duplicate question.